# Element UI use default theme

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Current i have a vue project that is setup using webpack.

I would like to start using [element UI](http://element.eleme.io/) for my ui library.

After I did

```
npm i element-ui -S
```

in my terminal

and added the code below in my app.js (entry point of whole app)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
Vue.use(ElementUI);
```

I am able to start using  and stuff throughout the app.

however, I notice that the CSS is not being applied.

What should I do with the css? How do I tell elementUI to apply the default theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured it out myself.

Looks like i just need to do

1. Install this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-theme-default)
2. Add import `'element-theme-default';` right after the elementUI import

Answer (score 6):

This worked fine for me:

npm i element-ui

in main.js:

```
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
Vue.use(ElementUI)
```

if you like to localize, you should do:

```
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'
Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale })
```

or to set default size of elements to small:

```
Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale, size:'small' })
```