# How to use custom theme in Element-UI with Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I have created custom theme in [element.eleme.io/theme](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/theme). You can download your work and after unpacking you get following structure and files.

```
style
|
 --config.json
|
 --theme
  |
   --index.css
  |
   --fonts
     |
      --element.icons.ttf
```

---

```
config.json
{"global":{"$--color-primary":"#FF8063","$--color-success":"#67C23A","$--border-radius-base":"15px","$--border-radius-small":"10px","$--box-shadow-base":"0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04)","$--box-shadow-light":"0 4px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"},"local":{"$--badge-background-color":"#FF6E4D"}}
```

---

index.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";.fade-in-linear-enter-active,.fade-in-linear-leave-active{-webkit-transition:opacity .2s linear;transition:opacity .2s linear}.fade-in-linear-enter,.fade-in-linear-leave,.fade-in-linear-leave-active{opacity:0}.el-fade-in-linear-enter-active,.el-fade-in-linear-leave-active{-webkit-transition:opacity .2s linear;transition:opacity .2s linear}.el-fade-in-linear-enter,.el-fade-in-linear-leave,.el-fade-in-linear-leave-active{opacity:0}.el-fade-in-enter-active,.el-fade-in-leave-active{-webkit-transition:all .3s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);transition:all .3s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1)}.el-fade-in-enter,.el-fade-in-leave-active{opacity:0}.el-zoom-in-center-enter-active,.el-zoom-in-center-leave-active{-webkit-transition:all .3s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);transition:all .3s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1)}.el-zoom-in-center-enter,.el-zoom-in-center-leave-active{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scaleX(0);transform:scaleX(0)}.el-zoom-in-top-enter-active,.el-zoom-in-top-leave-active{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scaleY(1);transform:scaleY(1);-webkit-transition:opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);-webkit-transform-origin:center top;transform-origin:center top}.el-zoom-in-top-enter,.el-zoom-in-top-leave-active{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scaleY(0);transform:scaleY(0)}.el-zoom-in-bottom-enter-active,.el-zoom-in-bottom-leave-active{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scaleY(1);transform:scaleY(1);-webkit-transition:opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);-webkit-transform-origin:center bottom;transform-origin:center bottom}.el-zoom-in-bottom-enter,.el-zoom-in-bottom-leave-active{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scaleY(0);transform:scaleY(0)}.el-zoom-in-left-enter-active,.el-zoom-in-left-leave-active{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);transform:scale(1,1);-webkit-transition:opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1),-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);-webkit-transform-origin:top left;transform-origin:top left}.el-zoom-in-left-enter,.el-zoom-in-left-leave-active{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(.45,.45);transform:scale(.45,.45)}.collapse-transition{-webkit-transition:.3s height ease-in-out,.3s padding-top ease-in-out,.3s padding-bottom ease-in-out;transition:.3s height ease-in-out,.3s padding-top ease-in-out,.3s padding-bottom ease-in-out}.horizontal-collapse-transition{-webkit-transition:.3s width ease-in-out,.3s padding-left ease-in-out,.3s padding-right ease-in-out;transition:.3s width ease-in-out,.3s padding-left ease-in-out,.3s padding-right ease-in-out}.el-list-enter-active,.el-list-leave-active{-webkit-transition:all 1s;transition:all 1s}.el-list-enter,.el-list-leave-active{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateY(-30px);...
```

Sorry for the format of the code, its basically plain css anyway.

My question is: how do I apply this theme to my app since there is unfortunately no documentation on that topic. There is nuxt global css config in nuxt.config.js, also there is styles folder and assets folder. If I put the code there - how do I get it to work?

this is what I went through and did not find the answer I was looking for:

[How to add custom theme to element-ui in nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901235/how-to-add-custom-theme-to-element-ui-in-nuxt)

[element-ui-use-default-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238166/element-ui-use-default-theme)

There is also newer version of [Element-UI/theme](https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/theming.html) but not super helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

I have used documentation from v. 3 in v.2 of Element.

I just went to my `nuxt.config.js`, removed default theme and replace it with the path to the `index.css`, like so:

```
// Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    // 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css', // comment out
    'assets/style/theme/index.css', // add
  ],
```

This way my styles are working well. Hope that helps some of you.